# a lot of information in richTextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a list with many line extracted from file and I want to display it a richTextbox with this code

```
foreach (string s in Dettaglio)
{
    txtDettaglio.Text += s + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

And Dettaglio definition is:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> Dettaglio = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
```

But it makes a lot of time to accomplish it there’s any other solution or I haven’t to use richTextbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: I'd use [`AppendText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx) instead of string concatenation:

```
foreach (string s in Dettaglio)
{
    txtDettaglio.AppendText(s);
    txtDettaglio.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

It *may* be faster to use concatenation to avoid calling `AppendText` twice:

```
foreach (string s in Dettaglio)
{
    txtDettaglio.AppendText(s + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Now it could be that that won't actually be any faster, but it's what I'd try to start with - the internal data structure of `RichTextBox` may need to do work in order to *fetch* the `Text` property, and using `AppendText` you may avoid it having to reparse text that it's already handled.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using StringBuilder will be faster

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in Dettaglio)
{
    sb.Append(s + Environment.NewLine);
}
txtDettaglio.Text = sb.ToString();
```